# Como cria um menu "ocultável"?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um Toolbar, e quero fazer uma barra de configurações nela. Porém, para que não ocupe espaço, gostaria que fosse possível ocultar/minimizá-lo, algo parecido com o chat do teamviewer.

Meu ToolBar (esta dentro de uma tela principal)

```
Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
contentPane.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
toolBar.setFloatable(false);// não deixa ToolBar mudar de lugar.
JLabel label = new JLabel("  Configurações   ");
toolBar.add(label);                  
toolBar.add(botaoConfig);   
botaoConfig.addActionListener(this);
botaoConfig.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
```

Vou colocar uma ilustração para ajudar no entedimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo bem resumido:

```
package testes;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

public class TelaSistema extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public JDesktopPane jdp = new JDesktopPane();
    public JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    public JMenu jmCadastros = new JMenu("Cadastros");
    public JMenuItem jmiEstado = new JMenuItem("Estado");
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    JButton botaoConfig = new JButton("Config");

    public TelaSistema() {

        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.EAST);
        toolBar.setFloatable(false);// não deixa ToolBar mudar de lugar.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("  Configurações   ");
        toolBar.add(label);
        toolBar.add(botaoConfig);
        botaoConfig.addActionListener(this);
        botaoConfig.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        toolBar.setBackground(new Color(230, 230, 230));

        // setSize(800, 600);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Sistema");
        getContentPane().add(jdp);
        setJMenuBar(jmb);
        jmb.add(jmCadastros);
        adicionaJMenuItem(jmCadastros, jmiEstado);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void adicionaJMenuItem(JMenu menu, JMenuItem item) {
        menu.add(item);
        item.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TelaSistema tela = new TelaSistema();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tem como adicionar um **[mcve]** dessa sua tela com a barra?

Comment: Olá acredito que a sua dúvida é a mesma que essa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601900/javafx-how-to-create-slide-in-animation-effect-for-a-pane-inside-a-transparent

Comment: @Phrxn essa pergunta é sobre javafx, a solução lá dificilmente vai servir para essa,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O mais próximo que consegui fazer para simular esta barra foi utilizar do recurso de zerar a largura da `JToolBar` toda vez que o botão fosse clicado.

Para controlar melhor quando contrair e quando expandir, substitui o `Jbutton` por um `JToggleButton`,  pois este possui 2 estados(selecionado e não selecionado), bastando apenas alterar a largura da *toolbar* conforme o estado deste componente.

Para usar, basta instanciar a classe abaixo como um `JPanel`, passando seu `JToolBar` como parâmetro, e em seguida, adicionar na sua tela:

```
    JPanel barPanel = new ToolBarPanel(toolBar);
    contentPane.add(barPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Segue a classe `ToolBarPanel`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

/**
*
* @author diego.felipe
*/

public class ToolBarPanel extends JPanel implements ItemListener {

    private final JComponent barComponent;
    private final int prefwitdh;
    private final int MINIMUM_WIDTH = 0;
    private JToggleButton botaoConfig = new JToggleButton(">>");

    public ToolBarPanel(JComponent toolBar) {
        this.barComponent = toolBar;
        this.prefwitdh = barComponent.getPreferredSize().width;
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        botaoConfig.addItemListener(this);
        botaoConfig.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        botaoConfig.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        botaoConfig.setFocusable(false);

        this.add(botaoConfig, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

            barComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MINIMUM_WIDTH, 0));
            ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setText("<<");

        } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {

            barComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(prefwitdh, 0));
            ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setText(">>");

        }
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

Veja em funcionamento no seu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Do jeito que está, ele reduz o toolbar a largura 0, mas caso você queira que, mesmo minimizado, seja exibido um tamanho minimo maior que zero, basta alterar o atributo `MINIMUM_WIDTH` para o tamanho desejado.

Comment: Era isso mesmo ! Muito Obrigado.